# Partial UPD in Diamond-Blackfan syndrome patients

Tags: pediatrics, genetics

I got the following question on a practice exam:

"In a 9-year-old patient, a diagnosis of Diamond-Blackfan syndrome is made. Exome analysis reveals the presence of a pathogenic de novo heterozygous variant in the ADS19 gene. The allelic fraction of this variant is found to be 32% in the patient's peripheral blood. After a few years, the disease spontaneously regresses. What clinical condition can reasonably be explained through the following mechanism?"

The answer to this question is "partial UPD", however I don't understand how partial UPD could cause regression in a disease. Could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Hi and welcome. This site requires evidence of an attempt to solve the question with a bit of research. A quote from a paper and a link to that paper is evidence. 32% implies mosaicism. Although I know nothing about partial UPD, maybe a search of "revertant mosaicism" would help. It commonly occurs with dermatologic disorders, but has been found in several types of anemia as well. (That's quite the practice exam!)

Comment: A related case: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5709125/